# How to install .tar.gz plugin in Eclipse

Tags: java, c++, eclipse

I try to install eclipse CDT with java support.
I've downloaded 2 files:

1. eclipse-cpp-luna-SR2-linux-gtk-x86_64.tar.gz
2. eclipse-java-luna-SR2-linux-gtk-x86_64.tar.gz

And after taring the first file I can start eclipse, but I don't understand how to install the second file (java support). I tried also to untar first the second file(and install eclipse Java), but still don't see option how to add the other file as plug-in.

Thanks for any suggestion,

Ran

Answer (score 0):

It probably is easier to add the Java support from within Eclipse CDT. Goto Help > Install New software, select the eclipse update site and select Eclipse Java Development Tools.

Comment: Hi, Is there a way to offline (without internet connection) to install plug-in of type .tar.gz ?

Comment: There is a good chance that it will work if you merge the plugins and features directories from the two downloads.